# How can I add Git to an existing SVN project?

Tags: git, svn

I have been using SVN for a project for past 8 months and I'm now in the process of switching to Git.

I was able to successfully import SVN into Git, but now I want to establish Git on my local workspace.

How can I establish Git & "sync" without affecting my code?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you mean, but [Git-svn](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-and-Other-Systems-Git-and-Subversion) is pretty good.

I used it several years ago. Based on my experiences then I'm not sure how much I would trust it if your project makes heavy use of Subversion branches, but maybe they fixed that. It wasn't a problem for my team because we used svn branches rarely.

Comment: The git to svn import was performed on the remote side. Really I'm trying to make the local switch so that I can give my team a how-to for their local workspace. So the far only answer I can find is "clone" and forget you had code already in the directory.